# Can a moon be asymmetric?

Tags: planets, solar-system

I'm writing a story related to 'symmetry' and would like to detonate an asymmetric moon. Would gravity allow this? Could a moon be any other shape but round?

Comment: How big is the moon?

Comment: yeah this all depends on the size. asymmetric moons exist but they are all small

Comment: Please wait a little before accepting an answer ;). People around the world who were sleeping may feel more... awkward answering now ^^, so you might miss a tip or two.

Comment: Once you detonate it the fragments will be asymmetric.  Maybe.  Or maybe more symmetric if they are molten globules and coalesce into spheres!  I like the idea that the detonation is done _because_ the moon is asymmetric.  Your fiction concept has engaged my imagination!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it can. You need not look further than out next neighbour outwards. The moons Phobos and Deimos of Mars are distinctly asymmetrical:

[image: Phobos and Deimos from wikimedia]

All that is required is that it is not massive enough to be formed into a globe by its own gravity, the so called [hydrostatic equilibrium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium).

Comment: The upper size limit is smaller than the equilibrium condition suggests. The reason is that, as long as the satellite is not tidally locked, it will undergo continuous flexing as it orbits the primary.